# Postfix increment and derefencing of pointer variable in the same statement - what is executed first and what is executed next

Tags: c, pointers, dereference, postfix-mta, postfix-operator

Suppose I have a variable var having a value of 3.

```
int var = 3;
```

Then I store the address of `var` in a pointer named `point`:

```
int * point = &var;
```

Now if the following operation (i.e. **DEREFERENCING + *POSTFIX*-INCREMENT**) is performed:

```
*point++;
```

what will be incremented - will the value `3` be incremented resulting in `var` containing the value `4`, or will the value of variable `point` be incremented, resulting in `point` containing the memory address NEXT TO the memory address it previously contained?

Comment: First google search result for `precedence pointer increment`, now you know how to Google them :)

Comment: Look at [C Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for such questions. Although C doesn't define precedence, this site extracts the "*effective precedence*" from C's grammar.